# unable to help(exec)

Tags: python

Ok, this is funny.

```
>>> exec("print")
>>> help(exec)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    help(exec)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

looks like exec is a statement, not a function, hence you cannot help() it. Is this expected or a bug? if expected, why? can you reproduce it on python3 ? I have Python 2.6.1 here.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, exec is a statement (and thus doesn't have a docstring associated with it.)

In Python 3.x, exec is now a function: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec
So it can (and does) have a docstring.

You'd get this same behavior for help(print), which also became a function in 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

yes, like my followers said but for me i usually do :

```
>>> help("exec")
>>> help("print")
```

and it work for python 2.* and python 3k

Answer (score 2):

Just put quotes around it (works for assert, etc. too):

```
>>> help('exec')
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#exec

In Python 3, `exec()` is a function. Apparently, in Python 2, `exec` is a statement but can be used similarly to a function.

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax

> Removed keyword: exec() is no longer a keyword; it remains as a function. (Fortunately the function syntax was also accepted in 2.x.)